# Store array with key value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two array `[14, 20 , 40 , 40]` and `["6:28 PM","7:28 PM","8:28 PM","9:28 PM"]`.
I want to have this as

```
[{x:14,y:"6:28 PM"},
{x:20,y:"7:28 PM"},
{x:40,y:"8:28 PM"},
{x:40,y:"9:28 PM"}]
```

I tried to push array with another array like `a.push(x:values,y:time)` but this is not working out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const ids = [14, 20 , 40 , 40];
const times = ["6:28 PM","7:28 PM","8:28 PM","9:28 PM"];

const result = ids.map((id, i) => ({ x: id, y: times[i] }));

console.log(result);
```

No relation to Angular though.

Answer (score 1):

With an arbitrary count of properties, you could take the arrays with name as keys and take a short properties object and build a new data set out of the given data.

> It works with an object which takes the arrays with the later key name as property ([short hand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)).
>
> ```
> { value, time }
> ```
>
> From this object an array of key/value pairs (the values are array) is taken and reduced with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).
>
> ```
> result = Object
>     .entries({ value, time })
>     .reduce( ... )
> ```
>
> This happens by taking an array as start value and by iterating the array with the values with [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
>
> ```
> (r, [k, a]) => (a.forEach((v, i) => (r[i] = r[i] || {})[k] = v), r), // callback
> []                                                                   // start value
> ```
>
> Before an assignment happens, the result set at the given index is checked and if not exist, a new object is taken as default value.
>
> ```
> r[i] = r[i] || {}
> ```
>
> With the key `k`, the actual value is assigned.
>
> ```
> (r[i] = r[i] || {})[k] = v
> ```
>
> The result is an array of objects with keys from the named variables and the values of the arrays.

```js
var value = [14, 20, 40, 40],
    time = ["6:28 PM", "7:28 PM", "8:28 PM", "9:28 PM"],
    result = Object
        .entries({ value, time })
        .reduce((r, [k, a]) => (a.forEach((v, i) => (r[i] = r[i] || {})[k] = v), r), []);
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Upvote for complexity (never seen this one), but the man can't even merge two arrays, that's a hell of a syntax to understand there ... Not really suited for this question !

Answer (score 0):

```
const values = [14, 20 , 40 , 40];
const times = ["6:28 PM", "7:28 PM", "8:28 PM", "9:28 PM"];

const myObj = values.map((value, index) => ({
 x: value,
 y: times[index]
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let a=[14, 20 , 40 , 40];
let b=["6:28 PM","7:28 PM","8:28 PM","9:28 PM"];
let result = a.map((t,index)=>Object.assign({x:t,y:b[index]}));
```

result will have as you desired

Answer (score 0):

```
let newArr = [];
a = [14, 20 , 40 , 40]
b = ["6:28 PM","7:28 PM","8:28 PM","9:28 PM"]
for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    let obj = {x: a[i], y: b[i]}
    newArr.push(obj)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [Pythons zip function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip). Works like a zipper on your jacket:

```
function zip(a, b) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var key in a) { arr.push([a[key], b[key]]); }
    return arr;
}

const ids = [14, 20, 40, 40];
const times = ["6:28 PM", "7:28 PM", "8:28 PM", "9:28 PM"];

const zipped = zip(ids, times)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function processor(values, times){
// Map function use two array value and return processed array of objects
   return values.map((value, index) => ({
     x: value,
     y: times[index]
   }));
}
// Pass two array as arguments for two which you want processed
processor([14, 20 , 40 , 40], ["6:28 PM", "7:28 PM", "8:28 PM", "9:28 PM"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var val = [14, 20 , 40 , 40,9];
var time = ["6:28 PM","7:28 PM","8:28 PM","9:28 PM"];
var resultArr = [];
for(var i=0;i<val.length;i++){
  resultArr.push({x:val[i],y: ((time[i] !== undefined)?time[i]:'')});
}
console.log(resultArr);
```